# some Escape Sequence Character not working using XCode

Tags: c, xcode

I am testing some Escape Sequence Character in C using Command Line Tool in xCode on El Capitan. This is the string I tested:

```
printf("\a111\b222\n");
```

The expected result was:

> bell noise followed by 112221

to my surprise, there was no bell sound at the start, \b did not move cursor one character back, and write from there on. Is this a Mac and xCdoe problem? If so, what do I need to enable all the escape characters.

Comment: Have you tested this inside Xcode? I believe the Xcode is simply not a fully compliant terminal emulator, and might not even support them.

Comment: where did that 1 came from in the output at the end?

Comment: yes, inside XCode using Command Line Tool option. Backspace moves cursor 1 character back, therefore it writes 1 three times, goes one back, and ads 2 three times. Result: 112221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How those escape sequences are interpreted is up to the terminal/shell where you execute the program. Not all terminals support all sequences.